# Inserting into MySQL database not working

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a simple problem while uploading texts from edittext into MySQL database. On my app I have been using volley library, so I followed tutorial on how to insert into database, so I apply all the codes. Once I click to save button on my app.

The app exit without any reason. Just closed directly when I clicked to button.

**Signature.java**

```
private SignatureView signatureView;
OutputStream outputStream;
final String insertUrl = "http://192.168.1.101/myfile/insertStudent.php";
EditText txt1;
EditText txt2;
Button btnSave;
final RequestQueue requestQueue = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signature);//see xml layout

    signatureView = findViewById(R.id.signature_view);
    int colorPrimary = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent);
    signatureView.setPenColor(colorPrimary);
    // or like signatureView.setPenColor(Color.RED)

    txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
    txt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.LastName);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Save) ;



    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("firstname", txt1.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("lastname", txt2.getText().toString());
                    return parameters;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });
}
```

Logcat

```
   05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.Transient', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support.<init>
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 5489 (Ljava/beans/Transient;) in Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support;
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0003
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.ConstructorProperties', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support.findConstructorName
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 5488 (Ljava/beans/ConstructorProperties;) in Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support;
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0006
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.Transient', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support.findTransient
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 5489 (Ljava/beans/Transient;) in Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support;
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0000
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.beans.ConstructorProperties', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support.hasCreatorAnnotation
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 5488 (Ljava/beans/ConstructorProperties;) in Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/introspect/JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support;
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0000
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? W/nAnnotationIntrospector: Unable to load JDK7 annotation types; will have to skip
05-18 11:14:16.354 13227-13342/? W/System.err: WARNING: could not load Java7 Path class
05-18 11:14:26.614 13302-13302/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-18 11:14:26.614 13302-13302/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9cc8cb20)
05-18 11:14:26.614 1521-1793/? D/audio_hw_primary: found out /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
05-18 11:14:26.614 2048-2160/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-Application: Application crash has been observed. 
05-18 11:14:26.614 2048-13351/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor W/BstCommandProcessor-Application: in sendHttpRequest, requestType is of CRASH_APP type but one of the requiredInfo is NULL, crashedApp = com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor.BstCrashedAppInfo@4e75e800
05-18 11:14:26.614 13302-13306/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 23% free 3621K/4664K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 5ms
05-18 11:14:26.614 13302-13302/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13302 SIG: 9
05-18 11:14:26.614 13302-13302/? D/AndroidRuntime: procName from cmdline: com.kyanogen.signature
05-18 11:14:26.614 13302-13302/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.kyanogen.signature
05-18 11:14:26.614 13302-13302/? D/AndroidRuntime: file written successfully with content: com.kyanogen.signature StringBuffer : ;com.kyanogen.signature
05-18 11:14:26.614 13302-13302/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kyanogen.signature, PID: 13302
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.kyanogen.signature.Signature$1.onClick(Signature.java:93)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4578)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18654)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 11:14:26.624 1866-1911/system_process W/InputDispatcher: channel '4e9e40a4 com.kyanogen.signature/com.kyanogen.signature.Signature (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
05-18 11:14:26.624 1866-1911/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '4e9e40a4 com.kyanogen.signature/com.kyanogen.signature.Signature (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-18 11:14:26.624 1866-2036/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4e9e40a4 com.kyanogen.signature/com.kyanogen.signature.Signature (server)'
05-18 11:14:26.624 1866-3187/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process com.kyanogen.signature (pid 13302) has died.
05-18 11:14:26.624 1866-3187/system_process W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{4ea2f998 u0 com.kyanogen.signature/.Signature t68}: app died, no saved state
05-18 11:14:26.624 1866-2036/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{4e9e40a4 u0 com.kyanogen.signature/com.kyanogen.signature.Signature}
05-18 11:14:26.624 1866-3187/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: com.bluestacks.appmart activityName: com.bluestacks.appmart/.MarketPageGrid callingPackage:   bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
    Sending app_launch intent for appName: التطبيقات pkgName: com.bluestacks.appmart
05-18 11:14:26.624 1866-3187/system_process D/WindowManager: in computeScreenConfigurationLocked() -- hardKeyboardAvailable :true  mHardKeyboardAvailable :true   mHardKeyboardEnabled :true
05-18 11:14:26.644 2048-13353/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1900K, 27% free 7088K/9592K, paused 7ms, total 8ms
05-18 11:14:26.644 2062-2062/com.bluestacks.appmart D/com.bluestacks.appmartMainActivity: Onresume called
    InitViews called
05-18 11:14:26.664 2048-13353/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: command: home 
05-18 11:14:26.664 2048-13353/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-CommandHandler: Launching home Activity, intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 }
05-18 11:14:26.664 2240-2240/com.bluestacks.appguidance D/GuidanceScreen.Utils: checkAdExists() called with: context = [android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@4e730eb4], hostPackageName = [com.bluestacks.appmart], ignoreOccurrence = [true], adScreenService = [null], forceLaunch = [false], doNotSendStats = [false]
05-18 11:14:26.674 1866-3188/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2936K, 34% free 10993K/16644K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
05-18 11:14:26.694 1866-3188/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2719K, 35% free 10899K/16644K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
05-18 11:14:26.704 1866-1884/system_process D/WindowManager: Sending appClickStats request with data: [package=com.bluestacks.appmart, appname=التطبيقات, appver=16.68, clickloc=system_server]
05-18 11:14:26.704 1866-3188/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.bluestacks.appmart/.MarketPageGrid} from pid 2048
05-18 11:14:26.724 1866-2066/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2574K, 35% free 10925K/16644K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
05-18 11:14:26.724 1866-3188/system_process D/ActivityManager: TopActivityInfo, pkgName: com.bluestacks.appmart activityName: com.bluestacks.appmart.MarketPageGrid callingPackage: com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor  bstSpecialAppKeyboardHandlingEnabled = false
05-18 11:14:26.724 1866-2409/system_process D/InputMethodManagerService: packageName=com.bluestacks.appmart.MarketPageGrid, activityName=null
05-18 11:14:26.744 1866-2066/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2558K, 35% free 10964K/16644K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
05-18 11:14:26.744 2048-13353/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: response: {"result":"ok"}
05-18 11:14:26.744 2240-2240/com.bluestacks.appguidance D/GuidanceScreen..AppLaunchReceiver: same as previous package, returning com.bluestacks.appmart
05-18 11:14:26.744 1983-4272/com.android.inputmethod.latin W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-18 11:14:26.744 1866-3188/system_process D/ActivityManager: Sending app_launch intent for appName: التطبيقات pkgName: com.bluestacks.appmart
05-18 11:14:26.744 1866-2409/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 13302 uid 10062
05-18 11:14:26.774 1866-2409/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2655K, 35% free 10924K/16644K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
05-18 11:14:26.774 1866-3673/system_process I/ActivityManager: Setting mBooting value to false, currently mBooted = true
05-18 11:14:26.794 1866-2409/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2603K, 35% free 10932K/16644K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
05-18 11:14:26.804 2048-13357/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: command: muteappplayer
05-18 11:14:26.804 2048-13357/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-Application: in isSystemReady, isBootCompleted true External storage status: mounted  External storage dir :/storage/sdcard  isExternalStorageRemovable:true
    returning from waitForSystemReady,  isSystemReady = true
05-18 11:14:26.804 2048-13357/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: response: {"result":"ok"}
05-18 11:14:26.814 2048-13358/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: command: StopApp com.kyanogen.signature
05-18 11:14:26.814 2048-13358/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-Application: in isSystemReady, isBootCompleted true External storage status: mounted  External storage dir :/storage/sdcard  isExternalStorageRemovable:true
    returning from waitForSystemReady,  isSystemReady = true
    in isSystemReady, isBootCompleted true External storage status: mounted  External storage dir :/storage/sdcard  isExternalStorageRemovable:true
    returning from waitForSystemReady,  isSystemReady = true
05-18 11:14:26.814 2048-13358/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-CommandHandler: Package : com.kyanogen.signature doesn't exist in secure applist, so setting isSecureAppsReady flag
05-18 11:14:26.824 2048-13358/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-CommandHandler: Broadcasting STOP_APP intent with data: {"package":"com.kyanogen.signature","isArmApp":false} isArmApp: false
05-18 11:14:26.824 2048-13358/com.bluestacks.BstCommandProcessor D/BstCommandProcessor-httpd: response: {"result":"ok"}
05-18 11:14:27.124 1866-1879/system_process D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{4e9a76f8 ActivityRecord{4e9488ac u0 com.bluestacks.appmart/.MarketPageGrid t1}}
```

Comment: "_the app exit without any reason_" There is a reason, you just aren't seeing it. If you can't tell us what the error is we can't really help you. You need to post the full logcat output when the crash happens.

Comment: Please add the logcat

Comment: sure am going to add the logcat now

Comment: `requestQueue` cant be null. Set a value for it

Comment: @petey but what should i put insted??

Comment: @UdiIdan i have edited logcat

Comment: @csmckelvey i edited my post with logcat brother

Comment: How/where did you define and initialize a `new` `requestQueue`?

Comment: @DSlomer64 i defined above onCreate method              final RequestQueue requestQueue = null;

Comment: Yes, you defined it as null and that's why you get a NullPointerException. You need to give it some value like `requestQueue = new RequestQueue()`.

Comment: Maybe go [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple) (or lessons prior to it):

Comment: @csmckelvey i tried to solve error brother i need some help.

Comment: I have already given all the help I can - The issue is the object is null and I have shown how to make it not null. There is nothing else I can do.

Comment: In case this is the missing ingredient for you, somewhere above the line @csmckelvey showed, define the null object like so: `RequestQueue requestQueue;`

Comment: Or just do `RequestQueue requestQueue = new RequestQueue();` and provide any arguments that might be required.

Comment: @DSlomer64 i removed the null value also same error

Comment: @DSlomer64  i have removed requestQueue.add(request);        the app works but it doesnt insert into database becoz there is no requestQueue.add(request);

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the error .
The solution is creating an object like this --> 
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how `RequestQueue` or anything else about what you're trying to do work, but from the URL I suggested, here's a possible little bit of help:

```
RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

// Instantiate the cache
Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

// Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

// Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

// Start the queue
mRequestQueue.start();
```

That looks like a minimal prologue to the proceedings since `RequestQueue` requires two arguments, a `Cache` and a `Network`. Hope this helps.

Comment: i need modification my code to your code . coz am not fully understand how to integrate your code. sorry

Comment: [Here](https://developer.android.com/s/results/?q=RequestQueue%28&p=%2F)'s more help